# Run ndk-build from ant

Tags: c++, eclipse, ant, java-native-interface

I use it from eclipse and it's always telling me this error message:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\js\Desktop\two-libs\jni\build.xml:3: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\android-ndk-r7c\ndk-build": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

But the ndk-build is in that folder. Here's my build.xml file:

```
project name="salut" 
  target name="compile"
exec executable="D://android-ndk-r7c//ndk-build" failonerror="true" exec
  target
project
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are running from a window OS...

Try changing from:
D:\android-ndk-r7c\ndk-build

to:
D:\android-ndk-r7c\ndk-build.cmd

That should notify windows the "ndk-build" is runnable.